# Chemscheme package interferes with captions

Tags: captions, chemistry, chemstyle, vertical-spacing

I would like a caption to be as close as possible to its figure. This can be easily achieved with `\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}`. However, this solution does not work if the package `chemscheme` is active.

With `chemscheme`, the option `skip=0pt` is simply ignored. This happens also for tables. How I can keep using `chemscheme`, but also bring the caption close to the figure/table?

Thank you to everyone who tries to propose a solution.

```
%example of the right square image
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{chemscheme} %removing this line gives the left square image

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{square.png}
   \caption{chemscheme is on}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>chemscheme</code> resets space between figures and captions]

Comment: +1: Nice MWE! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `\floatsetup{captionskip=0pt}` from the `floatrow` package that is internally used by `chemscheme`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemscheme} %removing this line gives the left square image
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup{captionskip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{square.png}
   \caption{chemscheme is on}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```